# bigquery - managing destination tables after creation when using 'Allow Large Results"

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

In order to run queries with large data, (returning "response is too large to return")
I set the allowLargeResults parameter to true. (in my code)
However, when enabling this parameter, a destination table must be created.

Do I have to delete this table manually each time ?

For each executed query, a separate destination table is needed, 
It seems to be difficult to manage this "create-delete" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to delete them manually.

For batch processing you can chain your queries like this:

```
select * from (select complex thingy from table join each big_table on complex = match)
   join more_stuff_table ......
```

You won't get the name of the temporary tables created normally after each query.

Comment: Note that you can also set an expiration time on a table via the tables.update() method. https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/update.